# python3 loading dist-packages from python2 on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have fresh ubuntu 16.04 setup for production.
Initially if when i type
`python --version` gives me `python 2.7` and `python3 --version` gives me `python 3.5`
but i want `python` points to `python3` by default, so in my `~/.bashrc`
`alias python=python3` and `source ~/.bashrc`,
After that i install `pip` using `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and when i type `pip --version` it prints `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` instead that i want packages to be installed into and get from `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`.
I have django application which is written with python3 compatible code.

**Update:**  I want to install other packages which have to load from `python3 dist-packages` not just `pip`. I don't want to remove `python 2.7` from ubuntu it will break other programs, i thought `alias python=python3` would install packages into python3.5 dist-packages as well.

Comment: You probably want ```python3-pip``` + a call like ```pip3```.

Comment: execute : `sudo rm /usr/bin/python && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: what about other packages like `python-dev mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
` i want them directly installed into `python3 dist-packages`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pip3 as the command.
`pip3 install coolModule`
Be sure to add to your bash profile.
`alias pip3="python3 -m pip"`

Comment: thanks dave, but i have many python3 packages to install, what do i do about them

Comment: @Srinivas Use eyllanesc 's recommendation for removal and symlinking . Then you can pip install as normal the python3 based packages.

Comment: i thnk it removes python 2 completely from ubuntu `sudo rm /usr/bin/python ` what this do

Comment: It's removing that symlink.

Comment: ok, so it installs packages to python3 dist directly when i use `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`

Comment: Python packages are installed via pip

Comment: i was thinking about debian packages